# Text is not wrapping inside flexbox in IE EDGE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I have a UL set to `display: flex` and lists with `flex-grow: 1`, so that all items will take equal spacing.

Inside each list item, I have a link set with `display: flex`, `justify-content` and `align-items` set to center.

When the window is too small to display all items, text inside the LINK will wrap in Chrome and FF but not in IE Edge :(

I have not found a solution so far. All help is much appreciated.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
li:hover a {
  background: #000;
}
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ffcc00;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">NAME HERE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">NAME HERE 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">NAME HERE 2222</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">NAME HERE 100000</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">NAME HERE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: have you tried `white-space:  normal` to `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex` to the `li`.

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKNdbv?editors=1100)

Comment: Legend! Thank you.